# Resharper adding new lines before semicolons

Tags: javascript, resharper

When typing the semicolon at the end of a function like so

```
function someFunction {
    return 'hello';
};
```

Resharper makes it do this:

```
function someFunction {
    return 'hello';
}

;
```

Is there a setting I can do to make this not happen?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to stop Resharper doing this (running on version 7.1.1) is to open the Options and go to the Editor section and disable the following settings:

1. Auto-format on semicolon
2. Auto-format on closing brace