# Visual Studio Community 2022 adding newline after semicolon c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When creating new properties in c#, everytime I press ; VS generates a new line, and I can't find the setting...

Anyone knows where to turn it off? Getting very annoying to remove all the new lines with simple auto properties.

I'm also using re-sharper. It is something that 'appeared'. Guess I accidentally pressed some hotkey.

Before adding semicolon:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkFN5.png)

after:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZrlU.png)

Looking through the settings and trying alot of new line settings but unsuccessful

Comment: That's probably ReSharper.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open the Options and go to the Editor section and disable the following settings:

1. Auto-format on semicolon
2. Auto-format on closing brace

Comment: Thanks! 

Found it here after CodeCasters reply:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908954/resharper-adding-new-lines-before-semicolons

Comment: Disabling autoformat is not the way. There are formatting rules active which the OP doesn't want. A manual format will reapply the undesired formatting…

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure R# formatter to place automatic properties on a single line. The setting you're looking for is probably "Line Breaks and Wrapping | Arrangement of declaration blocks | Place abstract/auto property/indexer/event declaration on single line".
[image: R# settings]